# Synchronize two disks having access to only one of them at a time

Tags: rsync, data-synchronization

I need to synchronize two large disks but I can access to them only one by one. So I need to divide the process in two steps:

1. save (only) the differences from `source` on the local smaller disk
2. apply them to the `destination`.

Is it possible to save the current state of `destination` to a file, to copy on the smaller disk only the differences? With rsync or other tools?

Something like:

```
# on `destination` disk:  
rsync <magic option> -o "status_file.delta"  destination/

# `source` to `temporary`:  
rsync <magic option> -i "status_file.delta" source/ temporary/

# `temporary` to `destination`:  
rsync -a temporary/ destination/
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes! But you'll need two copies of the data on the source disk: one current (the source), and one that matches the state on the destination.

1. Sync the source to the second copy and record what's changed:

   ```
   rsync -a --write-batch=temporary/delta source/ source2/
   ```

   `source` and `source2` should now match, and you should have a file named `delta`.
2. Swap disks an apply the changes to the destination:

   ```
   rsync -a --read-batch=temporary/delta destination/
   ```

   `source`, `source2`, and `destination` should now *all* match.

You can then continue to make changes to `source`, but *don't modify `source2`* until then next time you sync to `destination`.

Comment: Thank you, that's interesting and I didn't know it.
Unfortunately, it doesn't fit my case because I can't create a double copy of data in source disk.
Rsync provides _almost_ all the instruments to solve the problem (batch, fine control of the used heuristic with `--ignore-times` and `--checksum` [http://serverfault.com/questions/211005/rsync-difference-between-checksum-and-ignore-times-options]) but it misses the possibilty to save the current status.

Comment: If you switch your source disk to use a copy-on-write filesystem, such as BTRFS, then the copy will use almost no extra disk space.

Answer (score 0):

Given that rsync requires both complete sets of data visible at once, an alternative solution is required. You can do this using normal UNIX command easily enough:

1. Scan both sets of data, source and destination, independently:

   ```
   find source/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum > temporary/source-signatures

   find destination/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum > temporary/destination-signatures
   ```
2. Diff the two signature files.

   ```
   diff -u destination-signatures source-signatures > sync-diff
   ```
3. *Optional* Generate a script to delete removed files:

   ```
   grep '^-' sync-diff | xargs echo rm > delete.sh
   ```
4. Capture the changed files:

   ```
   grep '^+' | sed 's/.* //' | xargs tar Af file.tar
   ```
5. Carefully, run the `delete.sh` script in the destination directory, and then expand the tar file such that it places the files correctly.

If you have any files with spaces or special characters in their names, then you'll need to be more careful with the delete script and tar process. In particular, `xargs` won't do the job.